# Extraneous solutions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, examples-counterexamples

I just learned of extraneous solutions on the internet and thought, "could you both lose and gain solutions in one equation?" I think that, yes, you should be able to do that. However I haven't been able to come up with an example.

My question is this:

> What could be a simple equation where the most straightforward way of solving it will result in you both gaining and losing a solution?

Comment: You should never really "lose" a solution when solving an equation, if you're solving it right.... Losing a solution is typically a result of a mistake, like taking the square root of both sides of $x^{2} = 9$ and forgetting the $\pm$.

Comment: @coolpapa with loosing solutions, I mean divisions by something like $x-1$, so when you follow in the equation. If the equation had a solution at $x-1$, it would no longer have it because of the division. With gaining solutions I mean the equation containing a square root, and when you square it, it could suddenly be a equation with 2 solutions whereas one of them cause negative square root in the first equation.

Comment: Gaining solutions absolutely happens. But losing solutions shouldn't. The situation you describe is a mistake, not an artifact of the solving process. Say I have the equation $$ x-1 = x^{2} - 1. $$ I factor the left hand side and get $(x-1)(x+1)$. Then I have $$ x-1 = (x-1)(x+1).$$ Dividing both sides by $x-1$ is a mistake, because $x-1$ could be zero. So I should split my equation into two: Either $x-1= 0$, or I can divide by $x-1$ to get $1 = x+1$, or $x=0$. 

Gaining solutions is just something we have to live with, but losing solutions is just irresponsible. :)

Comment: @coolpapa Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but sometimes it makes life easier to multiply an equation by $1$ and thus "both gain and lose a solution", like so: if $f$ is a polynomial (over $\mathbb{R}$, say), then consider
$$\begin{align}f(x)&=\frac{x-a}{x-a}f(x)\\
&=1\cdot f(x) \\
&=f(x)\end{align}$$
for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$. It's difficult to manufacture an exact scenario where this would be optimal, though, although it does happen.

---

*NB*: Basically, the zero in the denominator is cancelled by the same zero in the numerator, so division by $0$ is avoided.

Also, as coolpapa points out in the comments, one should never really lose a solution when solving an equation properly (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: Is that what you had in mind, @Darksonn?

Comment: I don't think extraneous solutions are fallacious, exactly - they come from statements like "If $x = \sqrt{y}$, then $x^{2} = y$." That's true, but the converse isn't. So you can end up with statements like "If $x$ is a solution of $x = \sqrt{4}$, then $x^{2} = 4$, so $x=2$ or $x=-2$." That implication is true, just misleading, since $x=-2$ is not a solution. It's just that not all of the manipulations we do to equations are iff statements.

Comment: @coolpapa: Thank you.